# Microsoft SQL auth_scheme issue

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to troubleshoot an SQL issue while our database admin is out ill. We have three msSQL  2016 servers. Two of them have no issue the third we have a connection issue with a third-party app. I've spent hours looking at settings to compare and got this far reading articles...

On the working servers when I run:

```
SELECT distinct auth_scheme FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
```

I get:

SQL

NTLM

The server giving us issues I just get NTLM.

When I run:

```
SELECT  s.host_name, auth_scheme
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections AS C
JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions AS S ON C.session_id = S.session_id;
```

On the working server I get:

10.0.0.x  SQL

ServerName NTLM

On the problem server, I get the NTLM record but no SQL w/ IP.

These are the only differences I find. All are running in mixed Windows/SQL Authentication mode. There is no Active Directory or Domain Controler. I know enough about SQL to be dangerous. The only reason I found the above info was from dozens of articles.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on what to do next.

Comment: NTLM is the hashing method that windows uses. Can you show us the complete error?

Comment: Can you authenticate using windows authentication? Is SQL Server Authenticstion enabled(is it really mixed auth?)? (On the problem server)

Comment: The app shows: " The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with windows auth. MSG 18452 Level 14." The SQL Log shows: SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x8009030c, state 14 while establishing a connection with integrated security Reason AcceptSecurityContext Failed.

Comment: Does the SQL server use the same Domain as the client trying to connect?

Comment: Yes can authenticate using Windows. When I run  SELECT CASE SERVERPROPERTY('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly')   
WHEN 1 THEN 'Windows Authentication'   
WHEN 0 THEN 'Windows and SQL Server Authentication'  
END as [Authentication Mode] ;SELECT CASE SERVERPROPERTY('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly')   
WHEN 1 THEN 'Windows Authentication'   
WHEN 0 THEN 'Windows and SQL Server Authentication'  
END as [Authentication Mode] it returns 1

Comment: The client may need to authenticate using `<Server>\username` as user... Is thecuser set up on the server?

Comment: The app (SymmetricDS) runs on the same server

Comment: I've figured out I can get the app to connect to SQL using SQL auth. Windows auth still gives me the same untrusted domain error (even from the same machine).